# reference collapsing for local variables

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-inference, rvalue-reference

In a function template parameterized on `T`, the type `T&&` may or may not be an rvalue reference, depending on the value category of the argument:

```
template <typename T>
void function(T&& x)
{
    // ...
}

std::string some_named_string;
function(some_named_string);       // T&& is std::string&

function(std::string("hello"));    // T&& is std::string&&
```

Does the same rule also apply for local variables where the type is automatically inferred?

```
auto&& x = some_named_string;      // is x a std::string& here?
auto&& y = std::string("hello");   // is y a std::string&& here?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. `auto` is exactly specified as template argument deduction.